# How can I backup the list of languages I have set and ordered in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, backup, language

### Background

While I was testing an error in a web service I was using, I noticed that it did not work in a single language when no others were specified as 'backups' or 'fallbacks'.
Before going to test this, I wanted to backup this list that I use regularly when testing other cases since I go to switch their order frequently, in order to test this specific error case with an almost empty list of languages.

### Question

My question is how to back this up easily without having to manually add each language back, by say typing in or picking each language through the UI and adding them again.
I envision doing any of the following:

- using a built-in Import/Export feature in the browser like I have done with Bookmarks to use a backup file,
- copying a certain configuration file out and then back inside the 'active program configuration directory',
- or copying a string of all languages over into a certain piece of the application's UI or configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Method 1 - File-Based

For Firefox, I found a relevant file in my browser user profile, that can be accessed by either of these paths:

```
C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile_name>\prefs.js
```

or

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile_name>\prefs.js
```

that contains the following relevant lines for my problem:

```
user_pref("extensions.qls.backup_acceptlanguages", "sr");
user_pref("intl.accept_languages", "sr");
```

---

### Method 2 - Application-Based

I have also found these properties are accessible through the Firefox "about:config" interface by putting that string in the address bar and navigating to it.
I would presume this way is more preferable as the application is notified of the changes, but the other method is nice if you need a script to maintain the configuration external to the program itself.

Note for "<profile_name>", you may have several profiles, and will have to change the file in the correct profile folder.
You can check the name of the current profile's configuration and settings folder by navigating to "about:support" in the browser and clicking "Show Folder".  This will open the path to the correct folder in your OS' default file browser and you can copy the path or identify the name from that.

Another note, I have the second "qls" property because I have a Firefox add-on installed called "Quick Language Switcher", so you may not have that key without the add-on being installed, and in that case won't need to concern dealing with that configuration property.